# Unable to create an identical initrd on re-compression for Pop! OS 19.04

Tags: linux, pop-os, initrd

I've made changes to initramfs, but when i'm repacking, the obtained file isn't identical to the original file

I've pulled out the boot image with the help of dd using `dd if=INITRD.GZ of=main bs=1 skip=2092032`

Here's the binwalk of the original `INITRD.GZ` for reference:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: ".", file name length: "0x00000002", file size: "0x00000000"
112           0x70            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel", file name length: "0x00000007", file size: "0x00000000"
232           0xE8            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
356           0x164           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode", file name length: "0x00000015", file size: "0x00000000"
488           0x1E8           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin", file name length: "0x00000026", file size: "0x00007752"
31184         0x79D0          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
31744         0x7C00          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel", file name length: "0x00000007", file size: "0x00000000"
31864         0x7C78          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
31988         0x7CF4          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode", file name length: "0x00000015", file size: "0x00000000"
32120         0x7D78          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc", file name length: "0x00000036", file size: "0x00000000"
32284         0x7E1C          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin", file name length: "0x00000026", file size: "0x001F6C00"
2091696       0x1FEAB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
2092032       0x1FEC00        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 2019-04-18 20:46:45
11747186      0xB33F72        gzip compressed data, ASCII, from HPFS filesystem (OS/2, NT), last modified: 2068-09-07 18:42:10 (bogus date)
49031581      0x2EC299D       xz compressed data
```

`main` has 74796 blocks and doing `file -s main` prints out

```
main: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu Apr 18 20:46:45 2019, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 222015488 gzip compressed data, reserved method, has comment, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 222015488
```

How do i get the "**gzip compressed data, ASCII, from HPFS filesystem (OS/2, NT), last modified: 2068-09-07 18:42:10 (bogus date)**" in my output? from what it seems the `--ascii` option might have been used when making the gzip archive.. but the --ascii option only works on Windows (only non-unix systems) and also it changes the size of the main file when doing so (tested on FAT).. whereas on Ubuntu --ascii isn't even supported

My extraction environment is an Ubuntu VM with a FAT and an ext3 partition attached

when i use gzip with maximum compression i get:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             gzip compressed data, maximum compression, has original file name: "tmpnew", from Unix, last modified: 2021-11-27 16:37:03
49103704      0x2ED4358       xz compressed data
59437120      0x38AF040       Nagra Constant_KEY IDEA_Key: 10192431 49690929 AED9EB82
```

And with default compression i get **"MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 2"** at the bottom

Please guide me on what i'm doing wrong here